How to convert a detectron2 model into onnx returning bboxes, classes, scores and masks
I have to convert a detectron2 to onnx format that returns these 4 fields pred_boxes, pred_classes, scores and pred_maks:
pred_boxes: Boxes(tensor([[544.5436, 134.7947, 579.4568, 165.4393]], grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>)),

scores: tensor([0.9487],grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>),

pred_classes: tensor([1]),

pred_masks: tensor([[[False, False, False,  ..., False, False, False],[False, False, False,  ..., False, False, False],[False, False, False,  ..., False, False, False]]])

But I'm getting this issue when I try to convert it:
UserWarning: The exported ONNX model failed ONNX shape inference. The model will not be executable by the ONNX Runtime. If this is unintended and you believe there is a bug, please report an issue at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues. Error reported by strict ONNX shape inference: [ShapeInferenceError] Shape inference error(s): (op_type:If, node name: If_2619): [TypeInferenceError] Mismatched tensor element type: source=9 target=2(Triggered internally at ..\torch\csrc\jit\serialization\export.cpp:1421.)_C._check_onnx_proto(proto)
If I try to do it without the pred_masks, it works perfectly.
This is my code:
import cv2
import torchimport numpy as np
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.modeling import build_model
from detectron2.checkpoint import DetectionCheckpointer
from detectron2.data import MetadataCatalog
from detectron2.utils.logger import setup_logger
from detectron2 import model_zoo

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file("mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x.yaml")
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = "model5111_bboxAPs_81_77.pt"
cfg.MODEL.DEVICE = "cpu"
cfg.INPUT.FORMAT = "RGB"
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = (0.6)
cfg.MODEL.NUM_CLASSES = 2
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 2

model = build_model(cfg)
model.eval()
DetectionCheckpointer(model).load(cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS)

class ModelWrapper(torch.nn.Module):
    def init(self, model):
        super().init()
        self.model = model
    def forward(self, images):
        instances = self.model(images)
        instances = instances[0]
        pred_boxes = instances["instances"].pred_boxes.tensor
        pred_classes = instances["instances"].pred_classes
        scores = instances["instances"].scores
        pred_masks = instances["instances"].pred_masks
        
        print(pred_boxes)
        print(pred_classes)
        print(scores)
        print(pred_masks)
        return (pred_boxes, scores, pred_classes, pred_masks)

model_wrapper = ModelWrapper(model)

inputs = "demo1.png"
im = cv2.imread(inputs)
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
numpy_image = torch.from_numpy(im.transpose(2, 0, 1))
dummy_input = [{"image": numpy_image}]

torch.onnx.export(
    model_wrapper,
    (dummy_input,),
    "converted_model.onnx",
    opset_version=16,
    export_params=True,
    do_constant_folding=False,
    input_names=["input"],
    output_names=["result"],
    dynamic_axes={"input": {0: "batch_size", 2: "height", 3: "width"}, "boxes": {0: "num_boxes"}, "scores": {0: "num_boxes"}, "classes": {0: "num_boxes"}, "masks": {0: "num_boxes", 1: "height", 2: "width"}}
)

print("Model has been converted to ONNX and saved as converted_model.onnx")

Could you please help me?
Try to convert it to onnx format.

You can use tools/deploy/export_model.py to directly convert into onnx format.
https://github.com/nhannt69/detectron2/blob/main/tools/deploy/export_model.py
Command:
python tools/deploy/export_model.py --config-file [cfg file].yaml --sample-image [image].jpg --output weight --export-method tracing --format onnx MODEL.WEIGHTS [weight].pth  MODEL.DEVICE cpu

Good luck.
